# Error 1452 al crear FOREIGN KEY

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy aprendiendo a usar **SQL**, pero cuando quiero crear una *Foreign Key* para una tabla principal, me da error.

He truncado la tabla, le he dado `drop` y me sigue dando el mismo:

> Error #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

En realidad ya no sé qué más hacerle.

Así fue como cree la tablas:

```
create table PROFESIONES
(id_profesion int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
desc_profesion varchar (255),
fecha_insert datetime,
fecha_modificacion datetime);

CREATE TABLE PERSONAJES
(id_personaje int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
desc_personaje varchar (255),
id_familia int,
id_sexo int,
id_matrimonio int,
id_profesion int,
fecha_insert datetime,
fecha_modificacion datetime);
```

Así como le puse atributos:

```
INSERT INTO PROFESIONES
(desc_profesion, fecha_insert, fecha_modificacion)
values ("JUBILADO",now(),now());
commit;

INSERT INTO PROFESIONES
(desc_profesion, fecha_insert, fecha_modificacion)
values ("AMA DE CASA", now(), now());
COMMIT;

INSERT INTO PROFESIONES
(desc_profesion, fecha_insert, fecha_modificacion)
values ("ESTUDIANTE", now(),now());
COMMIT;

INSERT INTO PROFESIONES
(desc_profesion, fecha_insert, fecha_modificacion)
values ("CEO", now(), now());
COMMIT;

INSERT INTO PROFESIONES
(desc_profesion, fecha_insert, fecha_modificacion)
values ("AGENTE INMOBILIARIO", now(), now());
COMMIT;
```

Y así es como intenté hacer la FK:

```
ALTER TABLE PROFESIONES MODIFY id_profesion INT(11);

ALTER TABLE PERSONAJES 
ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_prof_pers(id_profesion)
REFERENCES PROFESIONES(id_profesion);
```

Pero ¡me da error!

Cambié al `int (11)` para que ambas tablas tuvieran el mismo tipo, pero nada funciona y con las demás tablas que hice sirve a la perfección, solo con esta no.

**Importante:** Trato de crear una relación entre el personaje (primary key) y la profesión del mismo.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir la definición de la tabla `PERSONAJES`? También vendría bien conocer la versión de servidor MySQL que usas. He tratado de reproducir tu problema y a mí no me provoca ningún error, teniendo en cuenta que el campo `id_profesion` de `PERSONAJES` sea de tipo `INT(11)`.

Comment: Gracias por responder! Tengo la versión 8.0 y en la tabla de personajes tengo lo siguiente:

CREATE TABLE PERSONAJES
(id_personaje int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
desc_personaje varchar (255),
id_familia int,
id_sexo int, 
id_matrimonio int,
id_profesion int, 
fecha_insert datetime,
fecha_modificacion datetime);

Esta es mi tabla central de consulta por así decirlo.

Comment: Una pregunta más, que podría parecer una pregunta absurda pero es importante: ¿La tabla `PERSONAJES` está vacía? En caso negativo: ¿Todos los valores de `PERSONAJES.id_profesion` son válidos? Si tuvieras algún `id_profesion` que no esté en la tabla `PROFESIONES` no vas a poder crear la relación.

Comment: ¿Podrías comprobar lo que te dije en el segundo comentario? Lo envíe prácticamente al mismo tiempo que el que tú me enviaste, quizá no lo hayas leído: ¿La tabla `PERSONAJES` está vacía? En caso negativo: ¿Todos los valores de `PERSONAJES.id_profesion` son válidos? Si tuvieras algún `id_profesion` que no esté en la tabla `PROFESIONES` no vas a poder crear la relación.

Comment: Hola, acabo de ver tu comentario, la tabla PERSONAJES no está vacía, y cada elemento de la tabla "id_profesion" aparece en la tabla PERSONAJES, en total son 6 ids para profesion y los mismos 6 tipos aparecen en Personajes.

Comment: Para asegurarte de que todo es correcto prueba la consulta SQL que te propongo en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que estás teniendo es que no es posible agregar una relación entre tablas si no existe coherencia entre los datos de ambas, es decir, que no puede satisfacerse la restricción de la nueva clave foránea.

Si tuvieras algún `id_profesion` en la tabla `PERSONAJES` que no esté en la tabla `PROFESIONES`, no podrás crear la relación.

Para detectar qué registros impiden la creación de la relación puedes hacer uso de la siguiente consulta SQL:

```
SELECT
  PERSONAJES.*
FROM PERSONAJES
LEFT JOIN PROFESIONES
  ON PERSONAJES.id_profesion = PROFESIONES.id_profesion
WHERE
  PERSONAJES.id_profesion IS NOT NULL
  AND PROFESIONES.id_profesion IS NULL
```

Cuando usas `LEFT JOIN` y no se encuentra un registro en la tabla `PROFESIONES` que coincida con el campo `id_profesion` de la tabla `PERSONAJES`, el campo en la tabla `PROFESIONES` aparecerá como `NULL`.

De modo que esta consulta obtiene los datos de la tabla `PROFESIONES` a través del campo `id_profesion` y se queda con aquellas relaciones que no pudieron satisfacerse detectando que finalmente no coinciden los valores de los campos. Con esta modificación tenemos en cuenta que el campo de origen pudiera valer también `NULL` (no asignaste una profesión a un personaje).

Una vez que arregles las incoherencias, podrás crear la relación.

Comment: Oscar muchas gracias por toda tu ayuda. Creo que ya encontré el error y es porque hay un campo nulo que venía así en la guía. Lo voy a revisar y te cuento cómo me fue.

Comment: En principio no debería haber ningún problema en que haya campos `PERSONAJES.id_profesion` que valgan `NULL`. He editado mi respuesta para dar soporte a ese caso.

Comment: Oscar mil gracias! Sí me sirvió! No sabe de la que me ha salvado. Un millón de gracias!!!!

Comment: De nada, ¡un placer ser de ayuda! ;) No olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Hola tienes que indicar a que tabla hacer referencia, y no es necesario indicar el tamaño del campo.

**EJEMPLO**

```
ALTER TABLE `MI_TABLA` ADD CONSTRAINT `MI_TABLA_fk_xxx` FOREIGN KEY (`CAMPO_DE_MI_TABLA`) REFERENCES `MI_TABLA_FORANEA` (`CAMPO_TABLA_FORANEA`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

El `ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE` son la restricciones que le quieras agregar tu.

En tu caso la query quedaría algo así:

```
ALTER TABLE `PERSONAJES` ADD CONSTRAINT `PERSONAJE_fk_001` FOREIGN KEY (`id_profesion `) REFERENCES `PROFESIONES` (`id_profesion `) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Recuerda que las restricciones debes ponerlas tu ajustándose a tus necesidades, yo he puesto el standar.

**EDITO PARA DEJAR IMAGENES**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí te demuestro que funciona. No he puesto restricciones, cosa que no debe hacerse, pero así no entramos en polémicas.

Espero te sirva, suerte.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte. Por desgracia la consulta SQL del OP es correcta. La opción `ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE` no es necesaria y no arregla el problema del OP porque no llegó a crearse la relación, así que la definición de qué hacer tras borrados o eliminaciones de la tabla de destino no afectan a la hora de crear la relación. PD: ¿A qué te refieres con "yo he puesto el **estándar**"? ¿A algún estándar SQL (por favor, indica cuál es) o a las opciones por defecto?

Comment: No se si te has fijado, el OP quiere establecer una relacion, PK-FK y el codigo que tiene para hacer esa relacion no es correcto. Mi query simplemente hace la relacion, las restricciones, como le digo tiene que establecerlas el.

Comment: Las opciones por defecto son las restricciones que he puesto, en una relacion 1:N

Comment: Disiento de tus afirmaciones. La consulta SQL para establecer la clave foránea del OP es correcta y sólo requiere crear los índices necesarios o arreglar los valores erróneos antes de su creación. Además, las opciones por defecto de `DELETE` y `UPDATE` no son las que dices, son `RESTRICT` ([por documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)): *For an `ON DELETE` or `ON UPDATE` that is not specified, the **default action is always `RESTRICT`**.*

Comment: Te he dejado unas imagenes para que veas que la query que propongo no tiene nada de malo.

Comment: Nunca he dicho que tus consultas sean malas, siento la confusión si has pensado eso. Trato de indicarte que la consulta que propones no ayuda al OP y con mis comentarios trataba de indicarte los motivos y corregir la afirmación errónea del comportamiento por defecto.